# Importing .MTL Files with .OBJ

Tags: texturing, import, obj

I recently purchased assets from Master 3D Reality.  When I import any .obj file, I'm not able to see the image textures.  The .mtl file came with the model along with the image files.  I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: Does Blender report any errors (in the UI, console, or in the Scripting workspace)? Have you have set the viewport shading to *rendered* or *material preview*?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures